# Curve along convex set

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, curves

Let be $C$ a non empty, compact and convex set and $S:=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$, where $n>1$. In many occasions our professor simply skips the part where we construct a path that connects two arbitrary point of $S$. I was wondering if it is possible to construct a curve that connects two such points of $S$ by the following idea:

---

As $C$ is bounded there exists a number $k\in\mathbb{R}$ sucht that $\Vert x\Vert_\infty \leq\frac{k}{2}$ for all $x\in C$. Let be $a,e\notin C$ and $a\neq e $.

1.) There must be a straight line that lies in $S$ which either connects $a$ with $(k,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$ or $a$ with $(-k,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$. Otherwise we can produce a contradiction regarding convexity of $C$. WLOG we assume it is $b:=(k,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$ and define $L_1:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $L_1(t):=a+t(b-a)$.

2.) There must be a straight line that lies in $S$ which either connects $e$ with $(e_1,k,e_3,\dots,e_n)$ or $e$ with $(e_1,-k,e_3,\dots,e_n)$. Otherwise we can produce a contradiction regarding convexity. WLOG we assume it is $d:=(e_1,k,e_3,\dots,e_n)$ and define $L_4:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $L_4(t):=d+t(e-d)$.

3.) Let be $c:=(k,k,e_3,\dots,e_n)$ and consider $L_3:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by
$$
L_3(t):=c+t(d-c).
$$
$L_3$ lies in $M$ as $\Vert x\Vert_\infty\geq k$ for all $x\in L_3([0,1])$.

4.) Let be $b:=(k,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ and $L_2:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with
$$
L_2(t):=b+t(c-b),
$$
which also lies in $M$.

The four line segments all lie in $M$ are and can be connected in such a way to form a path along $a\to b\to c\to d\to e$; in other words $L:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with
$$
S(t):=\begin{cases}
L_1(4t),&t\in\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\\
L_2\left(4t-1\right),&t\in\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
L_3(4t-2),&t\in\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right]\\
L_4(4t-3),&t\in\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right]
\end{cases}
$$
connects $a$ with $e$ and lies in $S$.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Imo the simplest way to show this is to translate your set to contain the origin and then shrink it to be strictly within the unit sphere (we can obviously assume both without loss of generality) and then prove the complement deformation retracts onto the unit sphere along the obvious straight-line homotopy. Since the complement is homotopic to a sphere, it must be path connected; no need to write the path explicitly.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, so is my approach wrong?